# Finding somebody for speaking German

Tags: learning, speaking, listening-comprehension

I’m searching someone or a group with whom I can speak German.

I understand very good and I write good, the problem that, until now, I haven’t had the possibility to speak as much as I need to. First, I get shy when I speak to a German person because I have the feeling that he doesn’t understand nothing what makes me more confused and stop to speak.

What are possible techniques to find somebody to help me (and talk to them)?

Comment: The answer to that will differ depending on where you currently live and especially whether that is a German speaking country.

Comment: I'm living in germany actually

Comment: What happens usually? Is it that you start speaking German and the other person switches to English? Or to your language?

Comment: Actually when someone see that I don't speak good german, he stop speaking, I mean he doesn't shoe his interesst to speak more

Comment: What's your native language? Maybe there is someone around you could help with your language in exchange...

Answer (score 10):

Skype offers a fantastic opportunity for learning languages online. You can have free, live conversations with native speakers, and even use video for a more complete immersion experience. Learning languages with Skype is very effective.

Finding a language exchange partner

The first difficulty, though, is finding willing native speakers. If you’re not in a country that speaks your target language (so you’ll want to use Skype), it’s not easy to make native-speaking friends.

A very good site for finding language exchange partners is The Mixxer. Create a profile listing your native and target language/s, and you’ll start getting requests very quickly.

If you’re learning Mandarin Chinese, you can also try the creatively titled Language Exchange Network. This isn’t as full-featured as The Mixxer, but all you need to do is create a profile and leave it, and let the requests come in.

Using Skype effectively

Once you’ve an exchange partner, try to persuade them to arrange your conversations into 20 minutes of one language, then 20 minutes of the other. A lot of people will simply talk in their target language and not let you use yours, which can end up with odd conversations that use both languages alternately – not very beneficial for your fluency. Don’t be afraid to just drop or ignore partners who aren’t co-operative – there are always more people.

Try to arrange a regular time to have your conversation (if you’ve got several exchange partners then it’s easy to have several conversations a week without being too demanding on their time) – this will make sure you get consistent practice in, and keep you motivated to continue.

Unless you’re at the level where you can easily chat away in your target language, it’s better to plan ahead a bit and think of some topics to speak about. This not only allows you to prepare specific vocabulary for the session and get more out of it, but also to avoid awkward conversations that fizzle out and put you off trying again.

Some (or even a lot) of nerves before language exchange conversations are inevitable. Remember that your exchange partner probably feels the same, and that ultimately you’re there to learn a language, not to impress people with your charisma and fantastic personality.

Comment: Thanx a lot for this website, I will check now.Do you have some tipps to learn how to speak perfectly geman.It's hard for me to speak german with german poeple bc I have the feeling that they don't wanna ear you when you speak bad or you do mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Du könntest versuchen, Dir einen [Tandempartner](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tandem_%28Sprachlernmethode%29) zu suchen. In Berlin findet man  beispielsweise [bei der SKB](http://www.skb.tu-berlin.de/contao/index.php/en/tandem.html) welche.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a great website that I use: www.lingq.com, it has a tutor-student scheduling system that can help you find a Skype tutor/partner. Also, check out their message boards.

Another good site is how-to-learn-any-language.com.  You can connect with other learners there and possibly find a speaking partner.